# Push notification not working in foreground

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, push-notification, unusernotificationcenter

When my app is running I sent notification from firebase, `UNUserNotification` delegate method called, I got notification and it is displaying on top, But when I sent notification from my API server,

```
func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceive remoteMessage: MessagingRemoteMessage)
```

firebase delegate is calling and I can fetch the data , but notification is not displaying on the top.

My code is below:

```
func registerForPushNotification(_ application: UIApplication)
{

    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
        // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
        let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
            options: authOptions,
            completionHandler: {_, _ in })
        // For iOS 10 data message (sent via FCM
        //Messaging.messaging().delegate = self
    } else {
        let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings =
            UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)

        application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
    }
    application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
    application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0

}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data)
{
    print("device token %@",deviceToken)

    var deviceTokenString = String(format: "%@", deviceToken as CVarArg)
    deviceTokenString = deviceTokenString.trimmingCharacters(in: CharacterSet(charactersIn: "<>"))
    deviceTokenString = deviceTokenString.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "")

    print(deviceTokenString)
    //saveDeviceIdinDefaults(deviceId: deviceTokenString)
    Messaging.messaging().apnsToken = deviceToken

//        InstanceID.instanceID().setAPNSToken(deviceToken, type:InstanceIDAPNSTokenType.sandbox)
//        InstanceID.instanceID().setAPNSToken(deviceToken, type:InstanceIDAPNSTokenType.prod)

}

// The callback to handle data message received via FCM for devices running iOS 10 or above.
func application(received remoteMessage: MessagingRemoteMessage) {
    print(remoteMessage.appData)

}

@available(iOS 10.0, *)
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
    print("Userinfo \(response.notification.request.content.userInfo)")

    if response.actionIdentifier == UNNotificationDismissActionIdentifier {
        print ("Message Closed")
    }
    else if response.actionIdentifier == UNNotificationDefaultActionIdentifier {
        print ("App is Open")
    }

    // Else handle any custom actions. . .
    completionHandler()


    //    print("Userinfo \(response.notification.request.content.userInfo)")
}

func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                 didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: Error) {
    print("Failed to register: \(error)")
}

@objc func tokenRefreshNotification(_ notification: NSNotification) {
    //  print("refresh token call")
    guard let contents = InstanceID.instanceID().token()
        else {
            return
    }
    // let refreshedToken = FIRInstanceID.instanceID().token()!
    let refreshedToken = contents//InstanceID.instanceID().token()
    print("InstanceID token: \(refreshedToken)")

    Constant.saveFcmToken(fcmToken: refreshedToken, key: "deviceid")
    //        UserDefaults.standard.set(refreshedToken, forKey: "deviceid")

    print("InstanceID token: \(contents)")
    connectToFcm()
}

func connectToFcm() {
    // Won't connect since there is no token
    guard InstanceID.instanceID().token() != nil else {
        print("FCM: Token does not exist.")
        return
    }

    // Disconnect previous FCM connection if it exists.
    Messaging.messaging().disconnect()

    Messaging.messaging().connect { (error) in
        if error != nil {
            print("FCM: Unable to connect with FCM. \(error.debugDescription)")
        } else {
            print("Connected to FCM.")
        }
    }
}
// [START refresh_token]

//MARK: FCM Token Refreshed
func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didRefreshRegistrationToken fcmToken: String) {
    // FCM token updated, update it on Backend Server
    print("Firebase registration token: \(fcmToken)")
    saveDeviceIdinDefaults(deviceId: fcmToken)
}


func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceive remoteMessage: MessagingRemoteMessage) {
    print("remoteMessage: \(remoteMessage)")
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
        options: [.alert,.sound,.badge],
        completionHandler: { (granted,error) in
            NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name("GetPollsUpdateNotification"), object: nil)
            //self.isGrantedNotificationAccess(data: remoteMessage.appData)
    }
    )

    //            let notifiDict = remoteMessage.appData as! [String:String]
    //            print(notifiDict)
    //            let title = notifiDict["title"]
    //            let message = notifiDict["message"]
    //            let image = notifiDict["image"]
}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
    print(userInfo)
}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any]) {
    print(userInfo)
    if application.applicationState == .active {

        //write your code here when app is in foreground
    } else {
        //write your code here for other state
    }
}

@available(iOS 10.0, *)
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void)
{

    completionHandler([UNNotificationPresentationOptions.alert])

    let userInfo = notification.request.content.userInfo as! NSDictionary
    print("\(String(describing: userInfo))")

    print(notification.description)
}
```

Could any one please help me?

Comment: Push notifications simply are not displayed when the app is in the foreground. You can present your own notification when the callback is called if it suits your app.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the way to handle this is using the following delegate method:

```
 @available(iOS 10.0, *)
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {

            completionHandler([.alert, .sound, .badge])

    }
```

Hope this helps.